# My function works with enhanced for loop but not a normal for loop

Tags: javascript

these top two functions return the number and the array

```
function getCustomerNumber() {
    let customerNumbers = 312;

    return customerNumbers;
}



function getWinningNumbers() {
    let winningNumbers = [];
    winningNumbers.push(12,17,24,37,38,43);

    return winningNumbers;


function checkNumbers(getCustomerNumber, getWinningNumbers) {
    let match = false;
    let text;
    let winNum = getWinningNumbers;
    let cusNum = getCustomerNumber;
    let i;

    for (i = 0; i < winNum.length; i++)
        if(winNum[i] == cusNum)
            match = true;


    if(match)
        text = "\n\nWe have a match and a winner!";
    else
        text = "\n\nSorry you are not a winner this week."

    return text;
}
```

there is an issue with ny checkNumbers function , it seems to work with a enhanced for Loop but not a normal loop

Comment: Please click the `<>` and create a [mcve] so we can learn what you mean by "enhanced" loop - I would REALLY suggest you added some brackets: `for (i = 0; i < winNum.length; i++) {
        if(winNum[i] == cusNum){
            match = true; return; }}` - you need to stop when found or use a indexOf/includes

Comment: You may need some `{}` there. Also `winNum.includes(cusNum)` would be far simpler.

Comment: `let winNum = getWinningNumbers();` **<--** should be a function call? The other one too?

Comment: ...and what's an *"enhanced loop"*

Comment: sorry i meant  i enhanced For Loop , i also added the two other functions used in the parameters  for checkNumber function

Comment: OK, what is an "*enhanced for loop*"?

Comment: here what i used :    for(let i in winNum)
        if(winNum[i] == cusNum)
            match = true;

Comment: You haven't described what "doesn't work" means. There are two possible values for `text`, and you haven't described which you're expecting and which you're getting. You should really take more time for formulate a complete question.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining winNum and cusNum as references to functions, and not actually calling them:

```
function checkNumbers(getCustomerNumber, getWinningNumbers) {
    let match = false;
    let text;
    let winNum = getWinningNumbers();
    let cusNum = getCustomerNumber();    // <---- parentheses...
...
```

Comment: still the same issue , doesnt run

Comment: Yes it does. Are you missing the closing bracket for the getWinningNumbers() in your code? What error do you get?